# Hunting the SQL bug: sp_executesql -- Msg 911, Level 16, State 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to execute certain script on various SQL Server instances. They use the database with a different identification. However, all the databases have the same table (same name and structure) that should be processed. Because of that I want to detect the name of the database, set it to a string variable, construct the SQL statement, and execute the constructed string via `sp_executesql`. The bare command that executes correctly is:

```
USE [1000574];
SELECT TOP 10 temperature_1, UTC FROM dbo.Data;
```

Then I am trying to execute the equivalent string with the `@database_name` placeholder:

```
DECLARE @database_name nvarchar(100);
SET @database_name = '1000574';

EXEC sp_executesql N'USE [@database_name];
                     SELECT TOP 10 temperature_1, UTC FROM dbo.Data;',
                   N'@database_name nvarchar(100)',
                   @database_name = @database_name
```

What I get is the following error message:

> *Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Database '@database_name' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.*

Where is the error?

Thanks, Petr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot parameterize the argument to `use`: it expects a literal.  Construct the query dynamically instead:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'USE [' + @database_name + '];' +
           'SELECT TOP 10 temperature_1, UTC FROM dbo.Data;';
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Looking at the `sp_executesql` documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), I thought that the parameter substitution is done via text substitution. But being a SQL beginner, I may be completely wrong and I possibly did not uderstood what the doc says. Are you telling me that the `sp_executesql` cannot be used for the purpose?

Comment: @pepr you cannot pass `@database_name` as a parameter to `sp_executesql` for this particular case. This is not strictly because of a limitation with `sp_executesql` per se, but mostly because of the fact that `USE` does not take a variable. Basically the use of sp_executesql (unless nested like in Brian's answer) has the same limitations as a pure T-SQL script. If I can't say `USE @database;` in pur T-SQL, then I can't ask `sp_executesql` to do so either, unless I build the command beforehand.

Comment: Well, but this is not clear from the doc. The doc says that the statement (the first argument of `sp_executesql`) is a Unicode string. It says that it *can contain parameters having the same **form** as a variable name*. This way, I have considered the `sp_executesql` a kind of template engine that replaces the placeholders in the string by the other arguments passed to the stored procedure. The second argument could help to convert the passed value to the string that should replace its placeholder. I thought that `sp_executesql` is a more convenient way of constructing the command string.

Comment: "Same form as a variable name" implies that it must work the same way a variable name would work in a naked T-SQL script. So you can use it where you would normally use it for variables / parameters, but not where a variable name couldn't normally be used.

Comment: (+1) Well, for me it can sound like "same form *syntactically* as a variable name". You probably build on your intimate knowledge of how it is really implemented. I can imagine the implementation where the replacement of placeholders is done before the compilation of the string with the SQL command. I am just explaining what I thought. ;)

Answer (score 2):

One more way of doing this:

```
DECLARE @database_name NVARCHAR(100),@sp_executesql NVARCHAR(100),@sql_cmd NVARCHAR(512);
SET @database_name = N'1000574';
SET @sp_executesql = @database_name + N'.dbo.sp_executesql';

SET @sql_cmd = N'SELECT TOP 10 temperature_1, UTC FROM dbo.Data;';
EXEC @sp_executesql @sql_cmd;
```

Comment: Thanks (+1). But who creates the `[1000574].dbo.sp_executesql`? Do I understand the trick to call explicitly the `[1000574].dbo.sp_executesql` that *prefers* its own database without the need to say `USE`? I tried, and it seems to work. But where the `sp_executesql` is actually located?

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @database_name SYSNAME;

SET @database_name = N'1000574';

SET @sql = N'SELECT TOP 10 temperature_1, UTC FROM '
    + QUOTENAME(@database_name) + '.dbo.Data;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Also why is there no order by to tell SQL Server what you mean by `TOP`?

Comment: The `SELECT` command was used simply to make the problem visible. The `TOP` was used only to make the result shorter in SSMS. The `USE` is actually needed not for the `SELECT`, but for the `CREATE MESSAGE TYPE...` and the suite used for the Service Broker. Because of that I need to generate the `USE [1000574]` command and the rest of the script. What I need is to convert the string name of the database to the database identifier to be used in the `USE`.

Comment: See what happens when you over-simplify the problem? Don't do that. There are smart people here who can figure out the best solution when they have *all* the information, not a dumbed-down version that doesn't reflect what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Sorry. I was focused on the line 1, i.e. on the `USE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply use the qualified name, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?ppud=4):

```
SELECT TOP 10 1000574..temperature_1, UTC FROM dbo.Data
```

The query can, of course, be built dynamically.